# Only show wordpress featured image when shared on social media

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook, image, wordpress-featured-image

A client has asked me for the following:

> For the featured image on the wordpress add post side we only want the featured image to be shown when we post to social media like Facebook. So the featured image shouldn’t be on the blog anywhere but just shown in meta data on social meta.

I am not too sure how to solve the problem, i have tried hiding it with css and ive looked around online.  The reason i ask on here is because i dont know if this is possible.  any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it as `og:image` tag and it will only show up on Facebook: http://ogp.me/

Comment: thank you, 

for anyone who comes across this i put this into the head section of the site

<?php
  $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
  echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>'; 
 ?>